# How to Handle DevExpress GalleryItem Right Click?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, devexpress

Today, I was working on a program that required me to isolate the event caused when user right-clicks a DevExpress GalleryItem. Having consulted the forums and documentation, I was unsatisfied with the provided answers, "walking away" feeling there was a better answer. The problem is *not* that the documentation isn't there, the problem is that the documentation for this matter is woefully disjointed and requires a great deal of digging. Again, even after consulting the documentation, I was left with the question: "How do I handle the right-click event on a `GalleryControl` containing `GalleryItemGroup`s?"

My question was a bit more specific: "How do I access the `GalleryItem`located under the cursor?"

**NOTE: I am not providing code for the initial questions as I am answering the question in Q&A Format, i.e. I don't have the code that led me to the above question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress provides a tool that will be helpful in this situation. Typically, click events are handled in the background by a [Hit-Testing Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing), something which requires a bit of finesse and thinking (though the algorithm and logic behind the algorithm is relatively simple). Essentially, the code in question must capture the location of the cursor at the raising of the event and compare that to the location of the displayed objects - what you do with that comparison is the complicated bit.

Fortunately for us, DevExpress removes the complicated bit, providing a `RibbonHitInfo` object, the documentation for which can be found [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsRibbonViewInfoRibbonHitInfotopic) (I encourage you to click around a bit, it's pretty interesting stuff). The `RibbonHitInfo` provides a number of utilities that make what happens after the comparison of the click and the underlying objects quite easy.

The fully-qualified identifier for that class is:

`DevExpress.Xtrabars.Ribbon.ViewInfo.RibbonHitInfo`

### Capturing the Mouse Location

First, after the mouseclick event is fired, you must capture the location of the click (in this case, I am utilizing the `MouseUp` event. Two things to keep in mind for the below code: first (1), I am looking to isolate the right-click event; second (2), the mouse event function header format can be found throughout the internet (MSDN, DevExpress, StackOverflow, etc.) - that's where I pulled it from, initially.

```
Private Sub GalleryControl1_MouseRelease(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal MouseEvent As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles GalleryControl1.MouseUp

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        'Capture the location of the click:
        Dim PointOfClick As Point = e.Location

    End If

End Sub
```

The above code does two things: first, the `If e.Button =` statement evaluates which mouse control sent the event; second, the X and Y coordinates of the mouse click are captured as a `Point` object for use, later.

### Instantiating the RibbonHitInfo Object

Next, we must decide where our click is in relation to the objects we are interested in accessing (here, we are dealing with `GalleryItem` objects). DevExpress provides the `RibbonHitInfo` class for this purpose. I'll display the code, then explain afterward.

**Note: The below code makes additions to the code, above.**

```
Private Sub GalleryControl1_MouseRelease(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal MouseEvent As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles GalleryControl1.MouseUp

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        'Capture the location of the click:
        Dim PointOfClick As Point = e.Location

        'Instantiate a RibbonHitInfo Object:
        Dim HitInfo As RibbonHitInfo = GalleryControl1.CalcHitInfo(PointOfClick)

        ' Decide Where the PointOfClick is in Relationship to Other Objects
        If HitInfo.InGalleryItem Then

            ' Do Something

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, the above code does two (2) things: first, the code instantiates the `RibbonHitInfo` object (explained in detail, below); second, the code evaluates the location of the `RibbonHitInfo` object (really the `PointOfClick`) by utilizing the available utilities - or, member functions.

To instantiate `HitInfo`, I call the `.CalcHitInfo()` function, passing a `Point` object to the invoked function. `.CalcHitInfo(aPoint)` returns, "...[in this case] information on the GalleryControl's elements at that location". For me, it is easiest to think of a `RibbonHitInfo` object as a `Point` object that can interface with other objects behind it (that's a bit of a stretch, I know).

`HitInfo` has a number of member functions provided by DevExpress that allow us to evaluate where `HitInfo` is located; in this case, I want to know if `HitInfo` (or `PointOfClick`, really) is within the a `GalleryItem` object contained by `GalleryControl1`. Hence, the code: `If HitInfo.InGalleryItem Then`. Through all of DevExpress' glory, the `RibbonHitInfo` object detects whether - at the time of click (?) - the click was made on top of another object; again, in this case, a `GalleryItem` object.

### What To Do If HitInfo Is Where You Want It

If `HitInfo` is where you want it, then you can do what you want! However, for the sake of example (and, for my purposes, accessing the object underneath the click), I will provide some code. And, again, the below code is an addition to the above code (though this time it's more of a snippet).

```
       ' Decide Where the PointOfClick is in Relationship to Other Objects
        If HitInfo.InGalleryItem Then

            ' To Access The Object Behind Hit Info:
            Dim ClickedGalleryItem As GalleryItem = HitInfo.GalleryItem


        End If
```

Here, I am able to access directly the `GalleryItem` object initially found "behind" the `PointOfClick`. Both the returned `GalleryItem` object and `ClickedGalleryItem` an be used just as if they were a `GalleryItem` object -- because they are. From here, you can access any of the properties, methods, etc. you wish.